# How to configure azure health check "pings" every few seconds for web app

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I want to configure a health check for my azure web app.
My web app is an API written using asp.net core, I have an endpoint "/healthcheck" which is simply trying to access the database. I want to configure such health check to be called every few seconds, and notify me(for example on email) if there is no access to the database or something like that. How can I achieve that?
P.S. By "configure such health check" I mean that it is either my endpoint might be requested every few seconds, or other approaches of similar functionality provided by azure for example might be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App Services have the built-in health checks, which should be exactly what you need.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/monitor-instances-health-check?tabs=dotnet

Else, if you want to probe your app fully from outside, there are Azure Application Insights Availability Tests https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/availability-overview